# how to not make conda up in my terminal and remove (base) from the front of my terminal prompt

Tags: bash, macos, conda

I have conda installed and everytime I open a terminal conda automatically run and put a (base) in front of my terminal prompt. I'm trying to turn off this conda function and need some help from here to get that done. below is my `.bash_profile` and please let me know how to modify it and don't make conda up in terminal by default. Thanks.

```
export PATH="~/go/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/zwang/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/zwang/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/zwang/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/zwang/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026383/why-does-base-appear-in-front-of-my-terminal-prompt

```
This can also be because auto_activate_base is set to True. You can check this using the following command

conda config --show | grep auto_activate_base
To set it false

conda config --set auto_activate_base False
source ~/.bashrc
To reactivate set it to True

conda config --set auto_activate_base True
source ~/.bashrc
```